# Spring Cloud Eureka: Works with maven and in IDE, but not as uber-jar

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a sample Eureka server project, which works fine when run either in IntelliJ, or with "mvn spring-boot:run". However, when running the uber jar directly with "java -jar eureka-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar", I'm getting the following stack trace:

```
2015-11-04 19:48:56.985 ERROR 138300 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerConfiguration]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Annotation @EnableDiscoveryClient found, but there are no implementations.  Did you forget to include a starter?
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:437)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:183)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
        at com.my.example.EurekaApplication.main(EurekaApplication.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Annotation @EnableDiscoveryClient found, but there are no implementations.  Did you forget to include a starter?
        at org.springframework.cloud.util.SpringFactoryImportSelector.selectImports(SpringFactoryImportSelector.java:75)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:429)
        ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Here's the POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.my.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>eureka-server</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>eureka-server</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>com.my.example.EurekaApplication</start-class>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server 1.0.3 pulls conflicting jersey versions,
    so we add 1.11 below and remove 1.13 in exclusions above -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
          <addResources>true</addResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


</project>
```

So I do have a spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server starter dependency, plus I don't have @EnableDiscoveryClient annotation anywhere in the project.

Here is the only .java file in the whole project:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaApplication
{    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaApplication.class, args);;
    }
}
```

Here is the application.properties file:

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.registerWithEureka: false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry: false
eureka.server.waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you using the shade plugin? The spring-boot plugin should do all of that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eureka **will not work** with the jersey version you specify (it didn't for me).

Use http://start.spring.io to generate starting projects.

This pom.xml does work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.my.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>eureka-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>eureka-server</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>Angel.SR3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Thanks Spencer, but this didn't help unfortunately (same issue). Is 1.0.3 the latest stable release? Which spring-boot version should go with 1.0.3?

Comment: Thanks Spencer. I did get it to work earlier this week -- I was simply missing "repackage" execution goal within spring-boot-maven-plugin, and yes, I also got rid of shade plugin. But your version is much cleaner and also works. Thanks so much for your help again!!

Comment: Thank you Spencer! It worked great. Just one comment (regarding your suggestion) I really think that's a great idea (use the  http://start.spring.io to get started the basis, at least, the pom.xml, etc.) but, unfortunatelly I did that, hoping that everything will be working fine, and in fact did not...   it was another error, but it didnt work. Anyway, thanks for sharing your experience, indeed your POM works great.